# undefined error from second index when iterating over json list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-web-api

My code runs as,

```
       $.ajax({
            url: "api/WepAPI/",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.length);
                $.each(result, function (index, element) {
                    alert(element.StartDate);                        
                });
            },
        });
```

while iterating it shows the first element's startdate correctly and for all other elements it returns the 
undefined message in the alert.

My WEBAPI contoller code looks like,

```
    public IEnumerable<Employees> GetAllEmployess()
    {
        EmpDataContainer context = new EmpDataContainer();

        return context.Employees.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Help me in sorting out this error...

Comment: The error may be in your controller; what does that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your data might not be what you are expecting or maybe it is missing something or perhaps it is lower/different letter case.

In either case, without begin able to see the JSON for result; it is not possible to identify the possible cause for this issue.

Can you please add the JSON for a typical result object?

You can use `console.log(result);` to output the JSON.

Comment: In the list, the first index contains the properties filled. From the second index it has no values

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging and browsing, I found that the problem was due to using the entity object itself which has navigation properties i.e., the object in turn has some child objects.

Then found a work around to solve the issue, created a view model and assigned the values needed to the view model.
make sure that the view model does'nt have child objects.